# Unable to read the HttpURLConnection.responseCode when HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode is enabled

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, socketexception, bufferedoutputstream

I want to upload a file to a web server. To avoid getting an OutOfMemory error on large files, I added the `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(2048);` method. This works fine when the server responds with a response code of 200. However, when the server responds with an error code like 403 (Access denied), the `connection.getResponseCode();` method throws an SocketException, and I am unable to retrieve the response code. The same error is thrown when I try to use `connection.getHeaderField(key);`.

**My code:**

```
    private void uploadTest(File src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://localhost:42019/upload");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.addRequestProperty("filename", "uploadedFile.txt");
            connection.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(2048);

            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int count;
                while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                bos.flush();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {}

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            readRCode(connection);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**The error:**

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:824)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:759)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1691)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
    at de.paull.cloud.Request.uploadTest(Request.java:53)
    at de.paull.cloud.Request.main(Request.java:397)
```

I tried removing the `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(2048);` line, and now I am able to read the response code and the response headers. However, when I attempt to upload a large file, I encounter a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error again.

I don't want to switch to another library because I've built my entire project using HttpsURLConnection.

Comment: You could try it with fixed length streaming mode, but I suspect the file is too large for the server so it is closing the connection.

Comment: @user207421 I have already tried this, and the result is the same as when using setChunkedStreamingMode. When using smaller files, I am still unable to read the response code. So, the problem remains. I don't think it has anything to do with the file size. The server sends a response with exchange.sendResponseHeaders and an error code like 403 before it even starts reading the uploaded file. However, I am unable to read the response code.